# Visual studio 2013 Migration : Cannot open include file: 'dxerr8.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I wrote a VC++ application in Visual Studio 2003 which uses DirectX lib
using "dxerr8.h" in my applcation to provide traces for directX messages.

I can find the file in the following path

**"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\PlatformSDK\Include\dxerr8.h"**

Now i am migrating my application to Visaul Studio 2013 which throws a compilation error

**Cannot open include file: 'dxerr8.h': No such file or directory**

I searched for the file in the Visual Studio 2013 installed folder, which is missing.

**"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC"**

1. Where is the PlatformSDK folder ?
2. Do i need to install the DirectX SDK to get rid of this error ?

**How to clear this problem ?**

Comment: DirectX evolves very rapidly, the version you target is already 15 years old.  That's 3 dog lives ago, no longer covered by the SDK, time to update.

Answer (score 0):

Current SDK has `DXGetErrorString` function. Removing the "8" from all the names in your code, should fix your problem.

Comment: I am using DXTRACE_ERR( TEXT("DirectSoundCreate8"), hr ); Trace messages. Also i tried removing 8 from the header file. which doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I guess, you don't have DirectX SDK. Can yo verify it? You can check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for info on how to check if you have required SDK or not.

Comment: I hope that is part of Windows SDK, so no need to install the DirectX SDK seperately

Answer (score 0):

DXERR8 was last shipped in the DirectX SDK (August 2007). DXERR replaces all uses of this older library in any case.

See [Where’s DXERR.LIB?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/24/wheres-dxerr-lib/) for a replacement for DXERR that avoids the use of the legacy DirectX SDK.